# Not able to install certain gnome-shell extensions

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed, and I use both Gnome shell and the Unity interface. This post is about a few problems that I am facing with gnome shell extensions.

I have a few gnome-shell extensions installed. For example, gnome-shell-extensions-pidgin, message notifier, etc. I also have the gnome-shell-extensions-common package installed which is required for fulfilling dependencies.

Now, whenever I am trying to install a few other extensions such as dock, user-theme, etc., the installation is complaining that there is a broken dependency with gnome-shell-extensions-common package, and that it is not being installed. However, I already have the package installed. Probably, as a result, gnome-tweak-tool is also not able to activate the gnome-shell extensions.

Any help as to why this issues is occurring would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that, there is a version confusion. and that's why the dependencies problem.

i suggest you remove all of your extensions.
and add the webupd8 ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

. as shown in this [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/try-new-mint-gnome-shell-extensions.html). and then install it all again from there.by going to the synaptic package manager. so you can see all the listed packages and extensions available in the ppa.

Comment: Thanks suli8 for your suggestion. I have both webupd8team and gnome3-team ppa's installed. May be that's why there is a version mismatch! I have currently got around it by using the extensions.gnome.org website. That worked.